# Method of quickly changing between view and controller in visual studio - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way of quickly switching between controllers and views in Visual Studio when developing ASP.NET MVC applications?

I find that the solution explorer has quickly become very difficult to navigate through simply due to the quantity of files that is in there.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Answering my own question
Yes there is.  There appears to be a default shortcut key
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

This will automatically switch between the two.
If you're on the controller/action it will switch to the view and vice versa.

Comment: Nice find. I never looked for it as I only have files open I work in (so `Ctrl`(+`Shift`)+`Tab`) works for me. I get _"Unable to find matching controller"_ from a view, but from any action method it indeed finds the appropriate view.

Comment: Perhaps you've done something custom - maybe your view names don't match your action names or something similar?
Sounds like you're more organised than me. My tab bar is usually one massive disorganised mess ;)

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the action -> go to view

Comment: There is no Go-To-View in the popup menu. How should I do?