# How to navigate view to its controller from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

The problem is solution explorer has 29 projects on it, also, project has both asp.net mvc and asp.net web forms structure.

In the MVC Section, there are approximately 100 subfolders in the Controller Folder and each folder has at least 3,4 controller. Views are totally in different location[not in the MVC Folder].

**My first question** [is there any tool that will show the relationships between pages for whole files in the solution explorer.]

**Second Question** [how can I go controller from its view easily ?]

Comment: +1 for the monstruosity of solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your Second Question is...

You can right click on the Index Method of the controller and you will see an option "Go To View" which will do exactly that.

Comment: thank you for the response, but the problem is i need to navigate from view to controller, not controller to view, however I found the solution in the routing config file

Comment: @MehmetErenYener If you found the answer to your question, can you please post it?

Comment: @Derrick I totally forgot this question. Searching on it again, I ll let you know once I found

Answer (score 5):

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17990357/1754743

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>

"This will automatically switch between the two.
If you're on the controller/action it will switch to the view and vice versa."