# How to navigate/switch between ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 project's views and controller actionresult method

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET 5 MVC6 RC1` and `Visual Studio 2015 Update 1`

I want to quickly navigate between the view (.cshtml) and the actionresult (controller method).

However I can't find such an option

Previous stackoverflow solutions don't work

1. When I right click I don't have a "Go To View Option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030950/how-to-navigate-view-to-its-controller-from-visual-studio)
2. Keyboard Shortcust <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> dont't work as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990356/method-of-quickly-changing-between-view-and-controller-in-visual-studio-asp-ne)